# Copy values and keys from one array into another

Tags: javascript

I have data that looks like this returning from an api

```
var data =   {
        "entities": [
            {

                "documentbody": Base64String,
                "filename": "http-status-code-cheat-sheet1.png",
                "filesize": 204326,
               "mimetype": "image/png",

            },
             {

                "documentbody": null,
                "filename": "http-status-code-cheat-sheet2221.png",
                "filesize": 204326,
                "mimetype": "image/png",
            }
        ]
    }
```

I would like to create a new array that looks like this

```
var images = [ 
{  imgsrc:(documentBodyValue),imgDesc:(fileNameValue)},
{imgsrc:(documentBodyValue),imgDesc:(fileNameValue)}
]
```

I have tried using the map function `let result = data.entities.map(a => a.filename);` 
but this only returns the values into a new array. How can i create a new array with different keys but values from the original array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return a new object from the map for each item.

```
let result = data.entities.map(a => ({imgsrc: a.documentbody, imgDesc: a.filename}));
```

Comment: I love javascript! This is so neat. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt is almost correct. You can use `{key: value, ...}` syntax to map to an obj instead of values. E.g.:

```js
var data = {
  "entities": [
    {

      "documentbody": 'Base64String',
      "filename": "http-status-code-cheat-sheet1.png",
      "filesize": 204326,
      "mimetype": "image/png",

    },
    {

      "documentbody": null,
      "filename": "http-status-code-cheat-sheet2221.png",
      "filesize": 204326,
      "mimetype": "image/png",
    }
  ]
};

let result = data.entities.map(a => ({imgsrc: a.documentbody, imgDesc: a.filename}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var images = []
data.entities.forEach(entry => {
    images.push({imgsrc: entry.documentbody, imgDesc: entry.filename})
})
```

Comment: `[].map` is specifically intended for this situation, there's no reason to reinvent the wheel using `forEach` and `push`